# Перевод чисел из строки в целочисленные числа

Tags: c++

Есть задача перевести числа входящие в строку в инт. То есть имеется строка на подобии 4.777.555.34
нужно получить числа 4, 777, 555, 34.
Идей вообще нет :-(

Comment: Или используйте split (вариантов в Инете - море, например, boost::split в вектор), или откусывайте в цикле по одному с помощью strtok. Или ещё как...

Comment: Посмотрите на формат `%n` в описании [fscanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html). В соответствующий ему аргумент (это д.б. указатель на int) будет помещено количество считанных scanf-ом байт

Answer (score 2):

Так как не указано откуда берутся входные данные, предположим, что у вас уже есть сформированная строка. Тогда можно пойти несколькими путями: использовать сторонние библиотеки или, как сказал @Akina, использовать `strtok`. Также можно использовать потоки ввода-вывода на основе строк. Его и рассмотрим.

Задача решается в два этапа: 1. Разбиваем исходную строку на подстроки, используя символ разделителя (в вашем случае символ точки `.`); 2. Преобразуем каждую подстроку в число и выводим результат.

Выглядеть это будет так:

```
std::string source = "4.777.555.34";

//разбиение на подстроки
std::stringstream strStream(source);
std::string round;
std::vector<std::string> subStrings;
char delimetr = '.';
while (std::getline(strStream, round, delimetr))
{ subStrings.push_back(round);}

//преобразование в число и вывод результата
for (auto str:subStrings)
{ std::cout << std::stoi(str) << std::endl; }
```

В строке  `std::stringstream strStream(source);` создаем поток ввода на основе нашей строки. Почитать про stringstream можно здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

В строке `while (std::getline(strStream, round, delimetr))` очередную подстроку из потока. Почитать подробнее: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

В строке `std::cout << std::stoi(str) << std::endl` преобразуем подстроку в число и сразу его выводим. Для преобразования используем `std::stoi()`, читаем про нее здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

В случае, если в строке будут кроме цифр и точек другие символы, на этапе преобразования можем получить исключение, так что при использования в реальной программе учтите это и добавьте соответствующие проверки или обработку исключений.

Answer (score 0):

Разбор списка чисел в начале строки с использованием формата `%n` в функции [sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Линеен, не требует дополнительной памяти, не портит исходную строку (как будет при ее разбиении на токены функциями типа strtok).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char str[1000];


  while (fputs(">>> ", stdout), fgets(str, 1000, stdin)) { // чтение строк

    // разбор списка чисел в начале строки
    char t[3],
      delim = ',';
    int spos, pos1, pos2;
    int v, n, nl = 0;

    spos = 0;
    pos1 = pos2 = -1;
    while ((n = sscanf(str + spos, "%d%n %1s%n", &v, &pos1, t, &pos2)) > 0) {
      ++nl, printf("v = %d\n", v);
      
      if (n == 1 || t[0] != delim) {
        spos += pos1;
        break;
      }
      spos += pos2;
    }
    if (n < 1 && pos1 > 0)
      spos--,
      printf("warning: delim after last number in pos: %d   ", spos);
    printf("total %d numbers,  str tail: <%s>\n", nl, str + spos);
    // Здесь, если требуется можете обработать информацию в хвосте строки
    // (после списка чисел)
  }
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```